# Adding tree routing protocol in ns 2.32

Tags: ns2

I would like to add tree routing protocol in NS2.32 . I have header and .CC files of this tree routing. would you please mention the steps for adding this routing protocol

Answer (score 0):

? Which "Tree protocol" is it about ?

MAC_DGTreeAgent ? TBMR__Tree-Based-Mesh-Routing ?

.... Please supply a link to the protocol in question.

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Comment: My project is based on zigbee tree routing